# How to run a javascript application in chrome dev tools and take in JSON file as an argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, google-chrome-devtools

I have a function in my app.js, and I want to be able to use it in Chrome Dev Tools, but how can I call this function in the dev tools and also take in a JSON file as the first argument?

```
const appFilter = (json, city) => {
  const filteredNames = json
    .filter((obj) => {
      return obj.location === city;
    })
    .map((obj2) => {
      return obj2.name;
    });
  console.log(filteredNames);
  return filteredNames;
};
```

Or is there another way to do this through command line? I cant see to get this working in Command line with `node app.js`

edit: a bit more info, I can open my file in Node by `require('./app.js')`
but I want to be able to call this function appFilter() with different inputs while in Node but I get the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: appFilter is not defined`

Comment: did you try make this global ? `window.appFilter = (json, city) => {...`

Comment: A common workaround/hack is to attach the function to the window object, so you can call it from the console: `window.appFilter = appFilter;` (right after the function was declared).

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot. You'll have to assign your entire JSON file content to a variable and use that variable as an argument for the function you want to execute in the devtools console.

Comment: so even after adding the window.appFilter? How can I input an external JSON in as the argument though?